# SQL how many records start with the same letter

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have thousands of records in a database in a column A.

I want to see how many start with each letter of the alphabet and all single digit numbers.

So i need a count and the letter associated to it. I also want to see all the two alphanumeric combinations i.e. aa ab ac ad ae etc. and their count.

Also with three and four characters etc.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666525/group-by-first-character

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can generally `GROUP BY` an expression like `LEFT(columnname, 1)`, which allows you to perform a `COUNT()` aggregate grouped by an arbitrary expression.  The most ideal substring function to use may depend on your RDBMS.

```
SELECT
  UPPER(LEFT(columnname, 1)) AS first_char,
  COUNT(*)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY UPPER(LEFT(columnname, 1))
ORDER BY first_char ASC
```

Likewise, to get the 2 character match

```
SELECT
  UPPER(LEFT(columnname, 2)) AS first_2char,
  COUNT(*)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY UPPER(LEFT(columnname, 2))
ORDER BY first_2char ASC
```

Some RDBMS will allow you to use the column alias in the `GROUP BY` rather than the full expression, as in the simplified `GROUP BY first_char`.

Note that I have upper-cased them so you don't get separate matches for `Ab, AB, ab, aB` if you are using a case-sensitive collation. (I believe SQL Server uses case-*insensitive* collations by default, however)

Comment: Probably worth noting that the UPPER would only be required if the source was using a case-sensitive collation...