# SQL Server: Group by First Character (i.e. Letter)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, alphabetical

How do I a query in SQL Server using T-SQL to return the counts of the first letter/character in a column's values?

Comment: The proper way would be to ask a question and then add an answer and accept it. Perhaps think of editing your post?

Comment: Ok, I changed it.  Thanks for the advice.  What do you mean by "accept think"?

Comment: But that's for Oracle.  I changed it to T-SQL (for SQL Server).  Would you just add mine as a comment to that post?

Comment: "think" -> "it". A common typo ;)

Comment: [A SQL Server specific dupe does already exist too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500638/sql-how-many-records-start-with-the-same-letter)

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(FileName, 1, 1) as first_letter, COUNT(FileId)  
FROM Files  
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(FileName,1,1)  
ORDER BY first_letter
```

I modified an example for Oracle that can be found here: 
[group by first character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666525/group-by-first-character)