# Using substring in Rails query the safe way

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, sql-injection

I'm currently writing a query to look in a table some grouped results in order to build an alphabetical pagination index.

The query I have looks something like the following (based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666525/group-by-first-character)):

```
criteria = "substr(%s, 1, 1)" % field_name
Posts.select(criteria).group(criteria).order(criteria).count(:id)
```

Now I would like to improve this query in order to avoid any SQL injection but I couldn't really find a way to sanitise it.

As far as I see there's no way to use LIKE for this particular query - or at least I haven't found it - and use a `where` clause.

Now the example is using a `Posts` entity, but in production it will be used with many kind of objects and I's like to have a generic system to specify a field name dynamically.

The only idea I had was to get the table column name and validate the field against that list before proceeding, although this may be overkilling in a production scenario.

The environment I have is Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.17, and a MySQL db.

**Update 1**

I'll define better the context: in the query above I'm using `Post` but what I really have it's an ActiveRecord query where I'm appending the `select` and `group` criteria.

Something like:

```
query = Post.where(:condition => something)
# .. do more stuff here

criteria = "substr(%s, 1, 1)" % field_name
query.select(criteria).group(criteria).order(criteria).count(:id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Post.attribute_names` to take columns of Post model then just check that columns contains your `field_name` and raise error if it doesn't contains.

Comment: The problem is that I have not the model on my hand when I append the `select` and `group` methods. Unless there's a way to find out the model having the ActiveRecord query I think this is not fit what I'm looking for.

Comment: At the end `attribute_names` did work also for the `ActiveRecord::Relation`. I'll mark this as correct answer.