# SQL query to display one record of each alphabet from a table

Tags: sql

lets say there is one table called 'phone_book' have columns name and contact_no.
How to write a SQL query to display only first row from each alphabet from the column 'name' ?

Comment: First, choose the database you are using.  I removed the incompatible database tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [group by first character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666525/group-by-first-character)

Answer (score 0):

You can use query like this,

```
Select Top 1 * from phone_book where name like 'A%'
UNION
Select Top 1 * from phone_book where name like 'B%'
UNION
Select Top 1 * from phone_book where name like 'c%'
UNION
Select Top 1 * from phone_book where name like 'D%'
.
.
.
.
.
Select Top 1 * from phone_book where name like 'Y%'
UNION
Select Top 1 * from phone_book where name like 'Z%'
```